# How to find the inverse of this multivariable function?

Tags: functions, inverse-function

I have a function $f(1+x,1-x)=(e^y+xe^{-y},e^y-xe^{-y})$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. I can show that the function is smooth, but I want to show that the inverse is also smooth. How do I construct the inverse?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is it written in such weird way. I mean $f(1+x, 1-x)$

Comment: A function of one variable is of the form $f(x):=$ expression in $x$, and a function of two variables is $f(x,y):=$expression in $x$ and $y$. Please give it a moment's thought of what you have in mind, or get bust.

Comment: The author probably means a function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, which maps $(1+x, 1-x)$ into $(e^y+xe^{-y}, e^y-xe^{-y})$. The domain is then a parametrization of a straight line, while the latter looks like some open region of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

So the question should probably be; if 

$f : (1+x,1-x) \ni \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto (e^y+xe^{-y}, e^y - xe^{-y}) \ni \mathbb{R}^2$, $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ then what is $f^{-1}$?